# Encontrar valores repetidos y consecutivos de un array en Javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estoy intentando encontrar valores repetidos y consecutivos dentro de un array, ejemplo:

```
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Es decir acá debería darme una alerta de que existen 4 valores repetidos con el número `0` seguidos el número 4 es una constante y es el máximo consecutivo que puede tener ese array.

Lo que estoy haciendo ahora es lo siguiente:

```js
var questions = new Vue({
    el: '#main',
    data: {
      res: null,
     contador: [],
    },
    methods: {
      add(){
         this.contador.push(this.res)
         console.log(this.contador)
      }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>

<div id="main">
<input type="radio" v-model="res" :value="1" name="radio"> 1 
    <input type="radio" v-model="res" :value="0" name="radio"> 0
    <br>
<button @click="add()">Agregar</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Lo que buscas es que te detecte los valores repetidos automáticamente ?

Comment: Si, cuando se de clic en Agregar ahí que tiene que hacer el cálculo solo puede existir como máximo 4 valores consecutivos es decir ya sea 1 o 0 (1,0,0,0, 1,1,1,1) por ejemplo ahi se desactivaría el boton o mandaría un alert.

Comment: esto no es um problema de vue, si no de js puro...que intentaste para solucionarlo?

Comment: @gbianchi, intenté con muchas soluciones dándole mi propia lógica, pero no logro conseguir ese resultado.

Comment: pues mostranos que intentaste asi podemos corregir tu logica

Answer (score 0):

La lógica es la siguiente:
Hacer un repaso de cada uno de los valores e irlos comparando con la lista original, en cuanto encuentre un valor igual se agregara uno a su valor unico, esta funcion te devolveria un json.

```
contarRepetidos = (miArray) => {
    let contadorDeValores = {}

    miArray.map(valor => {
        let contadorDeValor = 0;

        miArray.map(valordeArray => {
            if (valor === valordeArray){
                contadorDeValor++;
            }
        });

        contadorDeValores[valor] = contadorDeValor;

    });
    return contadorDeValores;
}
```

y para tu ejemplo se haria lo siguiente:

```
contarRepetidos([0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Comment: Estimado @Jairo, gracias por tu respuesta, pero no que trato de hacer es que cada vez que se presiona el botón: <button @click="add()">Agregar</button> agregar un elemento al array, esta debe alertarme cuando haya 4 '0' o '1' consecutivos, espero me deje entender, un saludo.

Comment: Ohhhhhh, ya entiendo, disculpa la confusion